# How to make CombineLatest3 return result if one publisher hasn't produced any values?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, combine

I have three publishers. Two which already produced value, and one that may or may not do it. I need to combine them and produce output.

```
var changeDay = NotificationCenter.Publisher.init(center: .default, name: .NSCalendarDayChanged

    var someDate: AnyPublisher<Date, Never> {
        Publishers.CombineLatest3($someInputBool, $someInputDate, changeDay).map { (a, b, c) -> Date in
            return <someDate based on a and b, but if day changes, the result will be different.>
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

If the day hasn't yet changed, the CombineLatest3 won't return anything as it waits for the initial value from c before running the clousure. How can I make sure the CombineLatest3 returns even if one publisher hasn't emitted a single value? I'm using `c` as a trigger here to recompute my custom date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend a value to the notification publisher. The prepended publisher will signal immediately:

```
let changeDay = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSCalendarDayChanged)
    .map { _ in () }
    .prepend(())
```

Note that I have mapped the `Output` type to `Void` here. That means I don't have to create a dummy `Notification` to prepend, but it also means the `c` variable in your closure will not have a useful value.

Comment: Just to note here that this does not seem to work for all cases. I've got three pretty elaborately composed publishers that I'd like to combine so I can subscribe once, however `prepend()` alone did not help in my case. I've had to split them up unfortunately and subscribe separately.